# Retrieve the Date/Time difference in a MongoCollection

Tags: date-and-time, databaselink, mongodb

Each of my MongoDB documents contain two date-string timestamps: namely a LogOndt and LogOffdt timestamp.
For example:

```
cursor=MongoCollectionAggregate[collection,
  {<| "$match"-> <|"EmployeeID"->"8BB4A991"|> |>
  ,<| "$project"-> <|"_id"->False, "LogOndt"->True, "LogOffdt"->True|> |>
  }
]

MongoCursorNext[cursor]
```

returns the Association

```
<|"LogOndt" -> "2020-05-30T07:45:42", "LogOffdt" -> "2020-05-30T07:46:28"|>
```

In Wolfram Language I import these date strings and compute the time difference by

```
DateDifference[LogOndt, LogOffdt]
```

However, as the collection is quite large, local processing in WL is getting time-consuming. Therefore, I would like to exploit the computing power of the MongoDB servers.

According to the MongoDB documentation the subtraction of two timestamps should work (the difference is in milliseconds, hence the division by 3600000 in the example):

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$endtime", "$starttime"]}, 3600000]}
  }}
])
```

Following the above example, my WL implementation of the subtraction of the two timestamps is

```
cursor=MongoCollectionAggregate[collection,
  {<| "$match"-> <|"EmployeeID"->"8BB4A991"|> |>
  ,<| "$project"-> <|"_id"->False
                   ,"LogOndt"->True
                   ,"LogOffdt"->True
                   ,"Duration"-><|"$subtract"->{<|"$LogOffdt"->1|>,<|"$LogOndt"->1|>}|>
                  |> |>
  }
]

MongoCursorNext[cursor]
```

but this generates an error:
MongoCursorNext::mongoliberr: C Function WL_CursorNext failed. Error from Mongo C Driver: "Unrecognized expression '$LogOffdt'"

Am I taking the right approach? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer. My main obstacle was the parsing of date-time string into a ISODate( ).

```
cursor=MongoCollectionAggregate[collection,
  {<|"$match"-> <|"EmployeeID"->"8BB4A991"|> |>
  ,<|"$project"-> <|"_id"->False
                   ,"LogOndt"->True
                   ,"LogOffdt"->True
                   ,"duration"-> <|"$divide"->{
                             <|"$subtract"->{
                               <|"$dateFromString"-><|"dateString"->"$LogOffdt"|>|>
                              ,<|"$dateFromString"-><|"dateString"->"$LogOndt"|>|>
                                 }|>
                                 ,1000
                               }|>
                  |> |>

  }
]

MongoCursorNext[cursor]
```

results in

```
<|"LogOndt" -> "2020-05-30T07:45:42", "LogOffdt" -> "2020-05-30T07:46:28", "duration" -> 46.|>
```

The milli-seconds are converted to 46 seconds, which agrees with the timestamps.